# Using a Neural Network to Predict Output From a New Observation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, prediction

I have constructed a neural network using Python's Keras package. My network's goal is to predict the price of house. Here is what my training dataset looked like.

```
    Price   Beds    SqFt    Built   Garage  FullBaths   HalfBaths   LotSqFt
    485000  3       2336    2004    2       2.0          1.0        2178.0
    430000  4       2106    2005    2       2.0          1.0        2178.0
    445000  3       1410    1999    1       2.0          0.0        3049.0

...
```

Suppose I have some new houses I want to analyze. For example, I want to predict the price of a house with

- 4 Beds
- 2500 Square Feet
- Built in 2001
- 3 Full Baths
- 1 Half Bath
- Lot Square Feet of 3452

How can I input these values into my network to receive a predicted price. Also, is there a way to have the network report some kind of confidence indicator?

For reference, here is what my network currently looks like.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

N = 16

model = Sequential([
    Dense(N, activation='relu', input_shape=(7,)),
    Dense(1, activation='relu'),
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=32, epochs=100,
          validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))

model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)[1]
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you'll want to use `model.predict()`, as documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict).

`model.predict()` takes as parameter a batch of inputs `x`. In your case you only have 1 input, so you could write this as:

```
x = [[4, 2500, 2001, 0, 3, 1, 3452]] # Assumes 0 garages
print(model.predict(x)[0]) # Print the first (only) result
```

Comment: thanks so much! Is there a way for me to get a probability or confidence interval as well?

Comment: By the nature of a Neural Network that is unfortunately non-trivial. It's technically possible to determine a confidence interval, but it really is a whole other rabbit hole that you probably don't want to go down. What you can do instead is determine your average error (or even the distribution) and assume that for your result.

Comment: what would be the best way to go about your suggestion?

Comment: I would do a 'errors = model.predict(X_test) - y_test)' to get some samples of error and then plt.hist(errors) to see the distribution that the errors make. Then you'll know what the error distribution around your answer would be. You could add the prediction for your specific case to all these samples so you have a distribution of where you specific case would probably be.